# Spring web application with profile

Tags: spring, applicationcontext, spring-profiles

I have a **spring** application with multiple profile like **dev,prod**. application running on `external tomcat`.profile are setting in the pom.xml file

**pom.xml**

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
            <repoManager>Manager1</repoManager>
             ..........
            </properties>
        </profile>
</profiles>
```

Project  have **applicationContext.xml** file.
One of the bean definition, we are taking **repoManager** the value from dev profile.
when i run the application, throwing the following error

```
rg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name '<Class name>' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Circular placeholder reference 'repoManager' in property definitions
```

How to run spring web application with profile **dev**

I have done following changes

- Added **spring.profiles.active=dev** in catalina.properties file
  [image]
- Added **setenv.sh** in tomcat **bin** folder [image]
- Added **spring.profiles.active=dev** on **STS** run configuration

Above 3 solution are not working.

How to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your exception is complaining about a "Circular placeholder reference". So maybe this answer will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61232758/7454336 I don't think that this is a problem with different profiles.

Comment: @ThomasMeinhart ,similar kind of error.am trying to taking value from profile.am bit confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Got the answer

Right click on the project -> Maven -> Select Maven Profiles... and pickup your profile.
[image]
No Need to do above steps.